# Change meta title when tab is not active

Tags: javascript, jquery, title, countdown, meta

I want to ask if I can change the meta title when the tab is currently not active. I made a little site with the [Countdown plugin of Keith Wood](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).
I added a small feature which changes the meta title to the remaining hours, minutes and seconds. So I don't have to click on the tab to see if the countdown is over -> Doesn't work yet. Here is the [website](http://www.reischl.tirol/countdown/?date=17.08.2015%2012:00).

If you are on the website, you can see that the countdown is working and the meta title gets replaced without any problems. But if you change to another tab, the meta title doesn't get updated anymore.

Comment: That will be done to safe resources.

Comment: In many browsers javascript will only execute while your are actively on the page.

Comment: Yeah, it is basically what Mouser and stefan said, You can not change it, depends of the browser, however you can show an alert, for example, in some browsers like chrome calls the tab focus and the user can see it.

Comment: I already thought that I can't do anything about it. :/
But thanks to you guys anyways.